# How to I send selected element from devTools page to chrome sidebar page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working on a chrome devTools extension. Basically I have a sidebar pane added to the Element panel.
**devtools.js**

```
chrome.devtools.panels.elements.createSidebarPane("ChromeTrast", function(sidebar) {
  sidebar.setPage('devTools/chromeTrastDevTools.html');
}
```

**chrometrastDevTools.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
  <p id="devTool-report"></p>
  <script src="../resources/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="../resources/mustache.js"></script>
  <script src="../element/chromeTrastElement.js"></script>
  <script src="../element/RGB.js"></script>
  <script src="chromeTrastSidebar.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Within devtools.js, I need to get the selected element ($0) and send it to chrometrastSidebar.js.

basically, I am looking to pass data from devtools.js > chrometrastSidebar.js

chrometrastSidebar.js is a source file from the html page of the sidebar.

I tried using chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval() but it didn't work.

I did some research but all are messaging from contentscript to bacground page.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

```
You would preferably use to get and receive as below accordingly.

chrome.extension.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
  console.log(response.farewell);
});


chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
 function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
 if (request.greeting == "hello") sendResponse({farewell: JSON.stringify(sender)});
});
```